# How do combat jets know when to launch flares to counter IR missiles?

Tags: military, fighter, jet, missiles, missile-lock

From [my related question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17693/do-fighter-jets-have-forward-looking-radar-warnings-for-missiles-and-when-was-t/17696?noredirect=1#comment42945_17696), it seems fighter jets do not usually track missiles by radar. Instead, they have a system that warns of radar lock.

So what about infrared missiles (heat-seeking missiles)? Flares are a countermeasure to these, so how does the jet know when one is incoming?

I would be pretty surprised if such a system didn't exist. I want to know more about that system and when it was first implemented.

Answer (score 19):

Actually most aircraft don't actively know when a missile is being fired at them. I have worked on helicopters and fighters that deploy counter measures.

The first is an IR jammer which we call a disco ball. It is made up of mirrors at different angles that resemble a disco ball. It radiates an IR signal at different angles to confuse the missiles.

The flares or chaff are fired periodically in known hot spots. This creates heat signatures similar to the engines and confuses the missiles.

There are active systems but they don't work well. I have seen a helicopter in testing suspended from a wire with countermeasures turned on. A missile was fired and the countermeasures didn't even get deployed. This is why they usually keep firing the flares or chaff in known hot spots.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How many flares could fit on a fighter jet or helicopter? It sounds to me like this approach would quickly run out of flares.

Comment: From memory on a helicopter, the left side has a self defence suite with 4 rows of 6 tubed.  So 24 on each side, up to 48. But don't quote me on the number. If you ever watch the news with a fighter jet in Afghanistan flying over a hot spot they continously fire flares every 2 or 3 seconds. Contrary to what movies display, aircraft don't stay in hot zones for a long time for obvious reasons

Comment: You should be able to Google some pics. The boxes will be just behind the doors above the skids. Just count the tubed.  No secrets there.

Comment: How disco ball reflects IR signal? AFAIK IR signal is just heat.

Comment: With mirrors. Here is a link on the specific system I worked on. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/ALQ-144

Comment: @Mark I recommend that you remove the last comment.  Asking for upvotes is seen as impolite (at best) and many people who might otherwise upvote won't when they see your comment. Additionally, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Mark I don't know how you got the idea that disco balls "reflects the missiles IR signal".  IR missiles don't transmit anything, therefore there is nothing to reflect.  Disco balls work by radiating large amounts of IR pulsed and modulated to confuse a missile.

Comment: I upvoted because this poster seems to have experience working in this field and can give us firsthand accounts. (Give us some time to upvote, we don't live on this site 24/7, at least not always :) @Simon I don't see anything wrong per se, but the disco ball could use better explanation. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think what he's trying to say is that it generates an IR signature somewhere other than the engines or center of the aircraft, so that when the missile leads its target (as it should), it is leading off center and will miss.

Comment: @DrZ214 Nope. Disco ball jammers (that's a bad term) aim to flood the receiver on the missile making it break lock. The acquisition beam of a most missiles is very narrow, a few degrees, and once lock is broken, it is very unlikely to re-acquire. The missile will simply fall away. It's too complex to detail here but in essence, the missile scanning head sweeps from side to side to track the heat source.  Disco balls emit a large source of modulated IR which floods the receiver and prevents it from tracking.  Modern missiles render this obsolete and disco balls actually attract them.

Comment: @DrZ214 Most IR missiles aim slightly off centre deliberately and explode alongside the target using proximity fuses.  Some fire out rods or chains which rip through the aircraft letting holed fuel tanks and engines disintegrating do the real work.  The aim of passive IR jammers is to stop lock.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, was late at night. The IR signal is transmitted from the ball itself confusing the missile. The disco ball or mirrors scatter the signal.

Comment: Also note that chaff (or "window") is an anti-RADAR counter measure and is not effective against IR seeking.  I would edit it out but you might have had something else to add?

Comment: @simon - The chaff can catch sunlight and engine heat and add noise to the missile's seeker picture, but on the whole you're right, it's not very effective against IR missiles. It was originally designed in WWII to confuse German ground radar sites, an early form of jamming.

Comment: @KeithS If you hold a flashlight up the the sun, are you going to see the light of the flashlight, or the light of the sun? There's almost no chance any IR missile is going to guide on chaff when the engine is vastly overpowering its heat signature.

Comment: @Simon Typically when countermeasures are fired, they are fired in a 'program' that fires both chaff and flare at the same time in a pre-determined mix. There are two types of countermeasures on the plane, but only one countermeasure system that can be fired. These programs are usually set up before the flight, and optimized against specific threats.

Answer (score 12):

Before continuing, much of the how's and why's of IRCM are going to be either speculation, or classified.  Nations will not freely discuss their actual methods of defeating opposing nation's IR capabilities.  Therefore, actual answers will be difficult to give.  However, here is an excerpt from Wikipedia regarding a specific missile warning system that may be found on military aircraft.  This represents one possible method used for *certain* types of aircraft.

> The AN/AAR-47 Missile Warning System is a Missile Approach Warning system **used on slow moving aircraft such as helicopters and military transport aircraft** to notify the pilot of threats and to trigger the aircraft's countermeasures systems.

The AN/AAR-47 passively detects missiles by their infrared signature, and uses algorithms to differentiate between incoming missiles and false alarms."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/AAR-47_Missile_Approach_Warning_System

Answer (score 6):

The infrared missiles are usually detected using a Missile Approach Warning Sensor (MAWS).

The Missile Approach Warning Systems are passive detectors, usually detecting either the infrared or ultraviolet rays emitted by the incoming missiles.

The infrared based systems detect the infrared waves emitted by the missile. The ultraviolet based systems detect the ultraviolet rays emitted by the missile's rocket motors and are more suitable for detecting missiles with solid rocket motors.

An example for the infrared based detector is the US-Israel PAWS, while the Swedish MAW-300 uses an ultraviolet detector. Some systems like the MWS-20 uses Doppler Radar to detect the missiles.

All these systems have their advantages and disadvantages, and in relation to your previous question, give a 360 degree coverage based on the location of their installation.

In most of the aircraft, these detection systems, along with the Radar Warning Receiver, which detect the Radar based missiles are integrated into the Self Protection System(SPS), which determines the threat level of the incoming missile and responds accordingly by firing chaff and flares.

Comment: I went to Wikipedia to cite that IR missiles are entirely passive and I found to my surprise that the AIM-9 has four IR emitters! +1

Comment: @ToddWilcox Those emitters are only on some models with IR proximity fuses.  They have nothing to do with acquisition and tracking and are only used to detonate the warhead when alongside the target.

Comment: Equally worth noting, some Air-to-Air IR missiles (like some variants of the AIM-9) can be given their initial steering cues via the FCR on the aircraft, this is active radar illumination on the target and can alert the pilot, causing him to trigger flares manually, even though the rocket and guidance system being used are IR. To say nothing of the fact that sometimes flares are triggered simply because the pilot sees the missile launch.

Comment: @Mark How long does a flare usually last? I want to get an idea of how many might really be needed for extended dogfights.

Comment: @DrZ214 The idea of an extended dogfight is somewhat far-fetched. If you're talking specifically about a 1v1, then you shouldn't be looking at how long the flare lasts but how many missiles you will need to duck. Airplane loadouts are extremely small - the F-16 can only carry 6 air to air missiles, the F-15 can only carry 8. If you assume something like 4 flares per missile, you're only look at 24-32 flares (assuming you are only optimizing for a single operation of 1v1 dogfight). You'll hit fuel limits well before you hit weapons or countermeasure limits, though.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Air friction is going to heat up the nose cone of a missile. It may not be an intentional IR emitter, but it will show up.

Comment: @MSalters  I would hate to have my life relying on _that_ being picked up against background clutter. I would have through that even from head-on, the scattered IR from the rocket motor would drown out the friction signature?

Comment: @MikeBrockington: AFAIK, that may not be a major source in mid-flight.